# ASP.NET Core api controller not being instantiated

Tags: c#, constructor, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I've created an API controller in my .NET Core 3.1 application (with an Angular frontend, C#).

For some strange reason its not being instantiated, if I try to call any methods on the controller from my Typescript service, nothing happens, it just skips past the call, no error message is generated but the method in the controller isn't accessed.

I've traced it to the fact that the controller isn't being instantiated but I can't see why. Has anyone else experienced this issue?

I inject a service into the constructor, but the service is being added to ioc at startup so it cant be that (along with the other services used), can anyone help?

This is part of the controller code, I've added a breakpoint to the constructor, but its not being hit. I had exactly the same issue with a previous controller I had added, I spent ages trying to figure out why it wasn't being instantiated, then suddenly, it was, despite the fact that I had made no code changes, so I'm baffled by this.

```
public class RepController : BaseApiController
{
    private readonly IRepService _repService;
    private readonly ILookupService _lookupService;
    private readonly IUserContext _userContext;

    public RepController(IRepService repService,
        ILookupService lookupService,
        IUserContext userContext)
    {
        Assert.NullCheck(repService);
        Assert.NullCheck(lookupService);
        Assert.NullCheck(userContext);

        _repService = repService;
        _lookupService = lookupService;
        _userContext = userContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you register your services to DI container? Can you show them?

Comment: Have you registered the Services &context in Start Up Class ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is inheriting form `BaseApiController`. You should try setting that to `Controller`.

You should also make your that you specify routing on your controllers. A [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to the docs about endpoint routing.

Maybe your endpoints dont have a correct return type, this should be of Type `ActionResult`

Comment: For an API controller, in .NET Core, I'd recommend using `ControllerBase`  as the base class. This avoids pulling in some view-related code for MVC controller methods that return views - that code is superfluous for an API controller method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I had this decorator

```
[Route("api/[controller]"]
```

instead of this

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]"]
```

its working now